# Does planting seeds with friends benefit me in any way?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-garden-flower-town

I noticed today that I can talk to friends in the Shopping Centre (or whatever it is called) and they will offer to plant seeds with me. Does that benefit me or my plants in any way?

Answer (score 2):

It means that you can control the colour of the resulting flower; assuming the plant comes in the colour, it will come out in their "Favourite" colour (the colour of their shirt).  This is useful for obtaining all the colours of plants, and certain jobs require particular colours either in general or for bonus points.